# What is the equivalent of geth's networkid in EOS?

Tags: nodeos

In geth, we basically connect nodes by networkid and that is how the network identifies that the nodes are all in one blockchain network. We have bootnodes to facilitate the connection of nodes.

I am starting up some nodes using nodeos. Is there an equivalent of networkid in EOS so that different nodes identify they are all in the same EOS blockchain network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, call `cleos get info`.

You will get the block chain id, which is unique to each instance, but shared for all nodes.

When you first start the node, you must use the same genesis.json.

Comment: What if there's a fork where 2 communities share the same genesis block but build on different chains?